# How to loop certain word only in list (Python)

Tags: python

I have list like this:

```
details = ['Salary:100', 'Bonus:200', 'Overtime:300']
for i in details: 
        print(i)
```

Result :

```
Salary:100
Bonus:200
Overtime:300
```

How can I loop only the words like below ?

```
Salary
Bonus
Overtime
```

Comment: `print(i.split(":")[0])`?

Comment: A Python string (every element of `details`) has [many methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) that you probably want to know by the heart if you are committed to Python programming.  In your particular case you may want to look at [the docs of the `str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method. ፨ ፨ ፨ ፨ ፨ EDIT I'm really serious when I say _"You probably want to know [the string methods] by the heart if you are committed to Python programming"_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split)

```
details = ['Salary:100', 'Bonus:200', 'Overtime:300']
for i in details: 
        print(i.split(':')[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

using split you can get the first part

```
details = ['Salary:100', 'Bonus:200', 'Overtime:300']
for i in details: 
        print(i.split(':')[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression

```
import re 
for i in details:
    pattern = re.compile(r'(\w+)')
    res = pattern.match(i)
    print(res.groups()[0])
```

Alternatively you can also use split method as answered by others.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The above comments work but I think what you need with ur list is to make it a dictionary
so you can iterate it easier:

```
dict = {}
```

and then

```
for i in details: 
        dict[i.split(':')[0]] = i.split(':')[1]
```

So now you have a dict which has 'Salary': 100,  and so on.
and you can iterate it like this:

```
for key in dict.keys():
    print(key)
```